# Double in object method not accepting fractional values?

Tags: c++, variables, double

I am having trouble with a C++ object-orientated script. When I create an object, I wish to calculate an `AttributeQ` based on its attributes `MyAValue`, `MyBValue`, and `MyCValue`.

While using the Visual 2010 debugger, I noticed that `TempAttribueQ` seems to always be `0` (except before it is initialized of course). Assuming `Delta != 0`, `BVal == Maximum`, and `DeltaA == DeltaC`, then `TempAttribueQ` should be `1/3` not `0`.

At first I thought it was a scope problem, but the variable is defined outside the `if-else` statements. I have tried initializing `TempAttribueQ` as some outrageous number, which it keeps up until the `if-else` statements when it becomes `0` when it shouldn't.

This is my code...

```
void SetMyAttribueQ(){

    double TempAVal = MyAValue;
    double TempBVal = MyBValue;
    double TempCVal = MyCValue;

    double Minimum = min(min(TempAVal, TempBVal), TempCVal);
    double Maximum = max(max(TempAVal, TempBVal), TempCVal);
    double Delta = Maximum - Minimum;

    double DeltaA = 0;
    double DeltaB = 0;
    double DeltaC = 0;

    double TempAttribueQ = 0;

    if(Delta == 0) {
        MyAttribueQ = TempAttribueQ; // this->SetMyAttribueQ(TempAttribueQ);
    }
    else {
        DeltaA = /* (a removed equation goes here... */
        DeltaB = /* (a removed equation goes here... */
        DeltaC = /* (a removed equation goes here... */

        if(AVal == Maximum)
            TempAttribueQ = (DeltaC - DeltaB);
        else if(BVal == Maximum)
            TempAttribueQ = (1/3) + (DeltaA - DeltaC);
        else
            TempAttribueQ = (2/3) + (DeltaB - DeltaA);

        MyAttribueQ = TempAttribueQ;
    }
}
```

What is preventing `TempAttribueQ` from getting a value of `1/3` or `2/3`? Or, what is causing it to be set to be set to `0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you divide one integer by another, you get an integer result. Change *either* or *both* the constants to non-integer to fix it - C++ rules will result in the other being converted to floating point before the division takes place. All of the following will work:

- 1.0 / 3.0
- 1 / 3.0
- 1.0 / 3

An integer will get converted back to a double invisibly, which is why you weren't seeing any errors in your code.

Comment: Thanks, @Mark (and everyone else who replied). Ah, how all too often it's the simplest things that trip us up or slip our mind...

I change the constants and the function works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

`1` is an integer and `3` is an integer so `1/3` uses integer arithmetic.

You want to use `1.0/3.0` to force double precision arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

`1/3 == 0` due to integer division, which is set to `TempAttribueQ`.

You need to do `1./3` which will produce `0.3333333..`

Answer (score 2):

Try 1.0/3.0 and 2.0/3.0. 1/3 and 2/3 are 0 due to integer division.

Comment: @nightcracker: this question is about C++

Comment: @Lie Ryan: Yeah, fail, I noticed and I did delete my comment, but it didn't register or something >.< I removed it now though.